# scala math round error

Tags: scala, math, rounding

Try this in scala:

```
val value1 = -1.3323651E7f
val value2 = Math.round(value1)
val value3 = value1.toInt
val value4 = Math.round(value3)

value1: Float = -1.3323651E7
value2: Int = -13323650
value3: Int = -13323651
value4: Int = -13323650
```

Why are `value2` and `value4` different from `value1` and `value3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in the [`java.lang.Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28float%29) module:

```
Math.round(a) = (int)Math.floor(a+0.5f)
```

Furthermore, computing with floating-point variables :

```
-1.3323651E7 + 0.5f = -1.3323650E7
```

Because 0.5f is first rounded to 1f to accomodate the difference.
Here is a partial solution for my previous problem:

```
val value2 = Math.floor(value1 + 0.499f).toInt
value2: Int = -13323651
```

Answer (score 1):

A `float` has about [7 significant decimal digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision).
So, given that your result depends on keeping all digits of your variable `val value1 = -1.3323651E7f`, it's not strange that you'll get trouble. I'd use `double` instead.